# Using windows built-ins (plus TeraTerm and perl, possibly) to emulate netcat's raw connection mode

Tags: windows, perl, netcat

So I'm trying to get windows to perform much like our Linux machines are able to.

Basically, we have a server set up to run a specific program on a port.  From a Linux box, running the following will display the help output for the program:

```
echo "--help" | nc servername portnum
```

Is it possible to do something similar to this in Windows, using only the build-in functionality of Windows 7, TeraTerm, and Perl (this will go with code that can be run on multiple machines in a lab, thus extra software can't easily be installed).

NetCat is detected as malware (backdoor agent) by many Windows anti-virus programs, so putting it into the shared directory wouldn't work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's not hard to write a Perl script to connect to a remote host and port and print its standard input to the socket.

```
#!/usr/bin/perl

use strict;
use warnings;

use IO::Socket;

my $host = shift @ARGV;
my $port = shift @ARGV;

my $remote = IO::Socket::INET->new(
                    Proto    => "tcp",
                    PeerAddr => $host,
                    PeerPort => $port,
                )
              or die "cannot connect to port $port at $host";
while (<>) { print $remote $_ }
```

(Shamelessly adapted from the first Google hit for "simple perl client", http://www.ccsf.edu/Pub/Perl/perlipc/A_Simple_Client.html)